# How to connect any application with Hive tables

Tags: hadoop, hive, devexpress, bigdata

I am working on Big Data to fetch data from **RDBMS** perform some operation and store the reults in **Hive table**. Now i want to connect with hive tables using **android**, **Devexpress** and some other web applications, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Download the Cloudera JDBC driver for Hive *(the Apache JDBC driver is cumbersome and has strange backward/forward compatibility issues)*

Comment: Cloudera JDBC driver for Hive is compatible with all applications ?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter can you share me some more details about JDBC driver for Hive ?

Comment: There's a 80+ pages PDF guide bundled with the driver. Give it a try.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks